# call main script function in script files called inside in shell script

Tags: shell

I am still learning to write shell scripting so i don't know whether this can be done.

I have a main script called main.sh

**Main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
function log {
    echo "[${USER}][`date`] - ${*}" >> ${LOG_FILE}
}

home/script/loadFile.sh && home/script/processData.sh
```

So my question is can i call my log function of main.sh inside loadFile.sh and processData.sh script file ?
I tried it but i got error

> line 1: log: command not found

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not portable, but in `bash` you can simply export the function definition:

```
export -f log
home/script/loadFile.sh && home/script/processData.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to prompt like this:

```
. home/script/loadFile.sh && . home/script/processData.sh
```

But if you have an `exit` command in your loadFile.sh or processData.sh then your main.sh will exist as well

Comment: Yes,I do have exit for error in my inner scripts but thats exactly what i need so i can track where exactly my logs stopped and at which stage or in which script i got error.This is what my requirement is if one script fails everything should stop.

Answer (score 1):

When you start `loadFile.sh` and `processData.sh` like you do, they are started as ordinary executables, so parent shell does not recognize then as shell scripts and new instance of shell interpreter is started for each script.  New shell interpreter does not know anything about your `log` function.

When you run `loadFile.sh` and `processData.sh` like this:

```
. home/script/loadFile.sh && . home/script/processData.sh
```

Shell treats them as shell scripts rather than as ordinary executables and executes in current context, thus making function `log` visible to them.  Also, any functions/variables defined inside `loadFile.sh` and `processData.sh` will be visible in parent shell after they will exit, and thus these scripts has many ways to damange parent shell, which makes such way unsafe in some situations.